# RMFloatingAnimation ANDROID VERSION (BALLOON ANIMATION)

Tags: android, android-animation

hi I would like to ask if is there a library that looks like this

https://github.com/carleihar/JRMFloatingAnimation

this library is IOS but I am looking for android

my goal is to create a bubble animation like exactly that moving baloon
I tried searching but no luck at all

Comment: check this https://github.com/plattysoft/Leonids

Comment: @NileshRathod none of this looks exactly as what I needed

Comment: https://github.com/asyl/ArcAnimator

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure but try checking this [animation library](https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-android).